# Problems with SSH ProxyCommand

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh

i have some problems with the ssh proxycommand. The authentication on the proxy works fine, but when i want to login to the remote-host it fails. The problem seems to be, that the proxy tries to login with my local rsa_key and not with the key stored on the proxy. Is there a way to fix this?

## This is what i want:

Local -- local rsa --> Proxy -- proxy rsa --> host

## The Config-file i use:

```
Host 192.168.178.32
HostName 192.168.178.32
User user
Port 22
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Host 192.168.178.30
HostName 192.168.178.30
User user
Port 22
IdentityFile home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -F ssh_config -p 22 192.168.178
```

Comment: Your second `IdentityFile` definition looks suspect. Aren't you missing a leading `/` from the path?

Comment: Cross-posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382659/problems-with-ssh-proxycommand http://askubuntu.com/questions/798564/problems-with-ssh-proxycommand

Comment: true shame on me :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably isn't the answer you want to hear, but you can't do what you're trying to do.

The `ProxyCommand` option in ssh expects to STDIN & STDOUT of the command to be connected directly to the destination host (`%h`) and port (`%p`). Thus it is the local `ssh` process which is talking to the remote `sshd`, not the proxy host's `ssh` process. And since it's the local `ssh` process talking to the remote, it doesn't have access to any ssh keys sitting on the proxy.

Ultimately you only have 2 options:

1. Copy the ssh key off the proxy host and install it locally.
2. Set up a local command which transparently executes `ssh` on the proxy. For example: `alias sshp='ssh -t 1.2.3.4 ssh'`

Comment: Yeah this is what i did, after days of searching for the answere. I now just copy the rsa-keys from the proxy and it works fine. Not ideal but, better than nothing ;) thanks